# Partial count aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

Note: Although my current focus is tsql, this could well be a more general sql question.

Consider the following valid-but-also-pseudocode sample query:

```
select 
    desiredKeyCols,
    case count(distinct productID) 
        when 0 then '0'
        when 1 then '1'
        else '2+'
    end as [Product Count Classification]
from orders
group by desiredKeyCols
```

The field [Product Count Classification] will return, for each `desiredKeyCols`, 0 if there are no associated `productID`s, 1 for 1, and 2+ for any higher number. However, `count(distinct productID)` will not stop its calculations once it has reached 2. It will happily continue to infinity, and then another operation will calculate the case.

I have seen the same thing arise multiple times.

**Is there a more efficient way to implement this?** If we want only 0/1+ class the answer is semi join (in/exists). But what about an arbitrary number of ranges?

Comment: Probably not.  In some databases, `count(distinct)` is VERY inefficient and there are work-arounds for the logic -- but none of them stop at "3".  However, SQL Server has a reasonable implementation as far as I know.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Having your expert self say "no" is an implementation nightmare...

Comment: This query is going to scan and group `orders` since that's where your grouping columns come from.  It's not going to matter much what your aggregate expressions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is not much you can do.  But here are two alternative ways to express the query that might have better performance.

If you have an index on "(desiredKeycols, productid)" and possibly "(desiredKeycols, productid desc)", you might try:

```
select desiredKeycols,
       (case distinct_cnt . . . )
from (select o.*,
             (dense_rank() over (partition by desiredKeycols order by productid) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by desiredKeycols order by productid desc)
             ) as distinct_cnt
      from orders o
     ) o
group by desiredKeycols;
```

This does not stop at "3", but it is possible that it will optimize better than `count(distinct)`.

Actually, a slight alternative would use only one index:

```
select desiredKeycols,
       (case cnt . . . )
from (select o.desiredKeycols, count(*) as cnt
      from orders o
      group by desiredKeycols, productid
     ) o
group by desiredKeycols;
```

In some databases this is significantly faster than `count(distinct)`.  However, I think SQL Server has a better optimizer, so it might not be a big win.